# Use a list to determine matplotlib colours

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am making a basic program using matplotlib which graphs a large number of points, and calculates a value to colour those points. My issue is that as the number of points gets very large, the time it takes to individually plot each point through a for loop also gets very large. Is there any way I can use one plot statement and specify a list to use the colours for each individual point? As an example,
Current method:

```
colours = [(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)] #The length of these lists is usual in the thousands
x = [0,1,2]
y = [2,1,0]

for i in range(len(colours)):
    plot([x[i]],[y[i]],'o', color = colours[i])
```

Whereas what I would like to use would be something more like:

```
plot(x,y,'o', color=colours)
```

Which would use each colour for each point. Is there any better way to approach this than a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not want to use `plot`, but `scatter`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colours = [(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)] 
x = [0,1,2]
y = [2,1,0]

plt.scatter(x,y, c=colours)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that worked perfectly! Thank you for the fast response. Would this also work with 3d scatters?

Comment: Yes, there should not be a difference.